# Statistics : Hypothesis Testing

Tags: binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I'm back with another question I can't solve. For this question, I was able to get part of the answer; nk$^{n-1}$(1-k), but I can't seem to see where you'd get the k$^n$ part.

[Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqrwr.png)

[Answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ2rR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the alternative hypothesis is $H_1: p>k$  then it is an right tailed test, where $c$ is the critical value. If the critical value is part of the `critical region`, then the critical region is $\{c,c+1,\ldots, n\}$.

In your case $c=n-1$. Therefore the critical region is $\{n-1, n\}$. The largest element is always $n$. Now you sum up these probabilities:

$$\sum_{x=n-1}^{n} \binom{n}{x}\cdot k^x\cdot (1-k)^{n-x}$$

$$=\binom{n}{n-1}\cdot k^{n-1}\cdot (1-k)^{1}+\binom{n}{n}\cdot k^{n}\cdot (1-k)^{0}=n\cdot k^{n-1}\cdot (1-k)+k^n$$

[image]

The source is [german wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomialtest#Signifikanzniveau_und_kritische_Werte) (translated).

$\alpha$ is the significance level.

Comment: I'm still confused on the k$^n$ part, do you do another binomial expansion but use n instead of n-1,and then add the two together?

Comment: @JiaXuanNg It has less to do with `binomial expansion` than the probabilities $P(X=n-1)$ and $P(X=n)$, where $X\sim Bin(n, k)$. I´ve calculated these two probabilities since $n-1$ and $n$ are the elements of the critical region. And yes, you have to add together since we want the probability for the (whole) critical region. Please, give a reply if you have additional questions or not.

Comment: Sorry, was asleep. I'm starting to get it now, thank you very much. So if the critical region was n+1,would n also be part of it? Or is it n+2?

Comment: @JiaXuanNg No problem. I appreciate to get a reply, but it musn´t be immediately. No, the critical region goes from the critical value to n. See my edit. At the table the yellow marked row refers to your case. If the lower bound is $c=n-1$ then the probablity of the critical region is $\sum_{i=c}^n B(i| p_0,n)=\sum\limits_{i=n-1}^n B(i| k,n)$

Comment: Ooh, I think I understand it now. I'm going to practice doing this types of questions. Thank you again!

Comment: @JiaXuanNg Nice. You´re welcome. When questions are arising at your exercises feel free to ask a new questions here in the forum.

Comment: Will do, have a great evening!

Comment: @JiaXuanNg Thank you, same wishes to you.